# Datastax - increase Cassandra IO thread number

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm facing an error like the below one:

> "All connections on all I/O threads are busy"

Until I will re-design the table to be optimal and to allow decent queries on it, **I want to increase the nr of IO threads**. Server memory is not a problem for me. Is there some config file I need to edit?

I'm using datastax driver for PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to increase the number of I/O threads you will need to utilize the Cluster Builder method `withIOThreads`

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
    ->withIOThreads(2)
    ->build();
$session = $cluster->connect();
```